# How to create two arrays from String in PHP for json output

Tags: php, json, database, web-services

I want to fire query in MenuTable and SubMenuTable (in loop).

But I have data is in String, like this:

```
"102_264,102_273,104_225,103_233,103_229,103_232,101_316,101_244,101_246,101_249"
```

Here `102_264` (`menuId_subMenuId`)

- `102` is `menuId`
- `264` is `subMenuId`

So, I want to separate this String then fire query in above tables. 
How can I do this?

Comment: `explode` by `,`, loop, `explode` by `_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **explode** function or use list and in the end convert it in JSON format with **json_encode** function. This code will work for you try this,

```
$str="102_264,102_273,104_225,103_233,103_229,103_232,101_316,101_244,101_246,101_249";

 $arrayComma = explode(',', $str);

 $menu = array();
 $subMenu = array();

 foreach($arrayComma AS $val){
      list($menu[], $subMenu[]) = explode('_', $val);
 }

 $json = array();

 $json=array("menu" => $menu, "submenu" => $subMenu);

 echo json_encode($json);
```

Happy coding..!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the explode function.

```
$array = explode($string,','); //Will contain array $array[0] = "102_264" etc

foreach($array as $arr){
   $explodedArr = explode($arr, '_');
   $menuId = $explodedArr[0]; //Contains 102
   $subMenuId = $explodedArr[1]; //Contains 264
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str='102_264,102_273,104_225,103_233,103_229,103_232,101_316,101_244,101_246,101_249';
$arr=array();
$arr=explode(',', $str);

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr) ; $i++) 
{ 
    $arr2=array();
    $arr2=explode('_',$arr[$i]);
    $sql="select * from abc where menu_id=".$arr2[0]." and sub_menu_id=".$arr2[1]."";
    echo $sql."    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to explode strings. Quick way for 3D array:

```
$data = "102_264,102_273,104_225,103_233,103_229,103_232,101_316,101_244,101_246,101_249";

$result = [];
// retrieve array by splittting string with every comma
foreach(explode(',', $data) as $value) {

    // retrieve Ids by splitting string with underscore
    $serie = explode('_', $value);
    $result[] = array(
        'menuId' => $serie[0],
        'subMenuId' => $serie[1],
    );
}
```

you will have everything in separate subarray, to loop it easily for queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it combines explode and map to give you your data in a single line of code.

```
$results = array_map(function($data){
    return explode("_",$data);
}, explode(",", $tmp));

foreach($results as $result){
    echo "menuId: " . $result[0]." subMenuId: ".$result[1]."<br />";
}
```

gives you

```
menuId: 102 subMenuId: 264
menuId: 102 subMenuId: 273
menuId: 104 subMenuId: 225
menuId: 103 subMenuId: 233
menuId: 103 subMenuId: 229
menuId: 103 subMenuId: 232
menuId: 101 subMenuId: 316
menuId: 101 subMenuId: 244
menuId: 101 subMenuId: 246
menuId: 101 subMenuId: 249
```